# undefined variable env in form in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When i include given code

```
 = form_for @order do |form|
      = form.hidden_field 'browserInfo[userAgent]',  value: request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

      = form.hidden_field 'browserInfo[acceptHeader]',  value: env['HTTP_ACCEPT']
```

then it gives me error

> undefined local variable or method `env' for
>
> ## <#:0x007f85cfa016d8> Application Frames All Frames

Please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo.

Replace

```
= form.hidden_field 'browserInfo[acceptHeader]',  value: env['HTTP_ACCEPT']
```

with

```
= form.hidden_field 'browserInfo[acceptHeader]',  value: request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT']
```